# Why is my trigger not working after using the usual way to fix it?

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

I need to use this trigger to do what I want to do.
It's a `BEFORE INSERT`.

```
DECLARE avaliacao_id INT;
DECLARE avaliacao_epoca VARCHAR;
DECLARE jogador_id INT;
    
SELECT id_avaliacao, epoca, id_jogador 
INTO avaliacao_id, avaliacao_epoca, jogador_id
FROM avaliacoes 
WHERE id_avaliacao = NEW.id_avaliacao;
    
SELECT id_avaliacao 
FROM avaliacao_spring 
WHERE id_spring = NEW.id_spring 
AND id_avaliacao IN (
    SELECT id_avaliacao 
    FROM avaliacoes 
    WHERE epoca = avaliacao_epoca 
    AND id_jogador = jogador_id
)   
LIMIT 1 
INTO @existing_spring_association;
    
IF @existing_spring_association IS NOT NULL THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Já existe uma avaliacao_spring associada ao mesmo spring e à mesma avaliacao.';
END IF;
```

It's giving MySQL Messages:

> #1064 - You have a syntax error in your SQL next to 'DECLARE avaliacao_id INT; DECLARE avaliacao_epoca VARCHAR; DECLARE jogador_id' on line 1

I googled it a bit and put this:

```
DELIMITER //
BEGIN
...
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

However the problem continues

> MySQL Messages: #1064 - You have a syntax error in your SQL next to '// BEGIN DECLARE avaliacao_id INT; DECLARE avaliacao_epoca VARCHAR; DECLARE ' on line 1

Comment: These are mysql triggers, not php. This has nothing to do with the PHP programming language, it's all SQL. I've re-tagged the question for you so hopefully you get more relevant help

Comment: Anyway you should post the exact, full error. 1064 is a syntax error usually, but it should come with a more detailed description. You can [edit] your post. See also [ask] if you need more guidance.

Comment: It look like you tried to start a trigger with `DECLARE`, then you tried to star the trigger with `BEGIN`, not with `CREATE TRIGGER`. Is that right? Did you look at any documentation or examples of trigger syntax?